# How to use selector to check all elements start with similar id is hidden in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, element, selector, hidden

```
<div id="reply_div1"> </div>
<div id="reply_div2"> </div>
<div id="reply_div3"> </div>
<div id="reply_div4"> </div>
```

**This one works:**

```
if ($('#reply_div1').is(":hidden") 
    && $('#reply_div2').is(":hidden") 
    && $('#reply_div3').is(":hidden") 
    && $('#reply_div4').is(":hidden"))
{
      #do something
}
```

**But this one does not work:**

```
if ($("div[id^='reply_div']").is(":hidden"))
{
      #do something
}
```

**How to use selector to check all elements start with reply_div are hidden?**

Comment: Are they hidden? Or are you looking for empty?

Comment: Always good to review the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector *Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true **if at least one of these elements** matches the given arguments.*

Comment: So your 2nd code is the same as using `||` rather than `&&`.

Comment: I need check if they are all hidden or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if *all* elements of a specific set are hidden you can use the `:visible` selector, then test if the `length` of found elements is `0`.

```js
if ($('div[id^="reply_div"]:visible').length === 0) {
  console.log('all hidden');
} else {
  console.log('not all hidden');
}
```

```css
#reply_div1, 
#reply_div2, 
#reply_div3, 
#reply_div4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reply_div1">1</div>
<div id="reply_div2">2</div>
<div id="reply_div3">3</div>
<div id="reply_div4">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the function. It will return you 1 if any element is not hidden otherwise 0.

```js
function checkVisibility() {
  let returnVal = 0;
  $("div[id^='reply']").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(":hidden")) {
      returnVal = 1;
    }
  });
  return returnVal;
}
console.log(checkVisibility());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reply_div1"> </div>
<div id="reply_div2" style="display:none"> </div>
<div id="reply_div3" style="display:none"> </div>
<div id="reply_div4" style="display:none"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this and will return **true** if any of the elements are hidden and **false** if they are not hidden

```
$("div[id^='reply_div']").is(":hidden")
```